# 1 year T-bill for buying a car in Europe

Tags: car, government-bonds, usd-us-dollar, europe

I live in Europe and I plan to buy a car exactly one year from now. I want to invest now approx. 32000 EUR in 1 year bonds to profit from the interest rate and to secure my money until I need it. My idea is that because of the globalized supply chain in the car industry, the prices of cars in EUR are strongly correlated with the value of the dollar, so I will be better off buying 2/3 1-year T-bill (in USD) and 1/3 1-year Germany bond (in EUR) to keep the value of my money for my purchase, even if I will be paying in EUR. Is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 5):

> because of the globalized supply chain in the car industry, the prices of cars in EUR are strongly correlated with the value of the dollar

What's your basis for this claim? Even if we assume this is the case, it might still vary widely by make/model.

The most obvious reason for investing in Treasurys over Bunds is the higher yield, i.e. a [carry trade](https://www.investopedia.com/carry-trade-definition-4682656).

This is far from being risk-free, since you're exposed to the EUR/USD FX rate, which is at a historical low (0.9754 as of 9/23).

If the EUR strengthens between now and when you need your money (in EUR), you might incur losses that are greater than the interest you earn on Treasurys.

Comment: Futures for June 2025 (farthest out) are 1.0247. So if you hedged currency risk, you'd be losing roughly 5% in roughly 2.75 years. Is that more than you gain from interest rate? Debatable, especially if ECB keeps raising rates.

Comment: Sure, you can hedge but it comes at a cost. I'm also not sure the average person has access to FX futures. Anything is debatable, especially if the Fed continues to hike more aggressively than the ECB or if Eurozone growth slows down, which is why I wrote "might".